# Glob not accepting multiple vars as path

Tags: php

I want to use the following code to get the total filesize of all .gz files. However as soon as I use `{$dir1,$dir2}` it doesn't work anymore. Using `{/path/1/*.gz,/path/2/*.gz}` works and `{$dir1}` works as well. Why is it not working?

I need to use multiple vars as the actual directory path will depend on a different input so I cannot hardcore all possibilities. It either has to be multiple vars as per the example or an array containing all the paths.

```
$dir1 = /path/1/*.gz
$dir2 = /path/2/*.gz

$size = array_sum(array_map('filesize', glob("{$dir1,$dir2}",GLOB_BRACE)));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$size = array_sum(array_map('filesize', glob("{".$dir1.",".$dir2."}",GLOB_BRACE)));
```

**EDIT**

As the reason given by @ippi

Comment: they actually are recognized as variables, the problem is that the brackets are removed because php sees them as part of string-interpolation syntax. (But this solution works!)